# ContenType Name is not being translated

Tags: 2010, resource-files

We have a content type

So, in the content types xml we have something like this:

```
 <ContentType ID="0x01010047B1CC563D1FA04EAD263BA38ADFBA0C06" Name="$Resources:SPNLMeetings,ContentType_AgendaPointAttachment_Name;"
```

I double checked the filename and the key of the resource.

And in the resources we have something like this:
For english:

```
<data name="ContentType_AgendaPointAttachment_Name" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Agenda Point Attachment</value>
  </data>
```

french

```
<data name="ContentType_AgendaPointAttachment_Name" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Annexe au point</value>
  </data>
```

dutch

```
 <data name="ContentType_AgendaPointAttachment_Name" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Bijlage agendapunt</value>
  </data>
```

so, the transaltions are there, when I checked the 14 HIve, the translations are there also.

I also executed stsadm -o copyappbincontent.

Comment: Have you enabled the MUI features on the SharePoint site collection and activated French and Dutch languages?

Comment: yes, other labels are translated in the same site collection.

Comment: something I could notice is that the first time the content type was done, they hardcoded some labels, and some others were translated. So the existing lists based on that content type are not transalted, but new lists are translated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the problem and it is an internet explorer problem.

Here I commented about it

http://levalencia.wordpress.com/2012/09/20/sharepoint-2010-custom-ribbon-actions-labels-wont-translate-in-internet-explorer/